# Maximum # of Results in a Sitecore Droplink field?

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

In Sitecore 6, one of my templates contains a "Droplink" field bound to the results of a particular sitecore query. This query currently returns approximately 200 items.

When I look at an item that implements this template in the content editor, I can only see the first 50 items in the field's dropdown list.

How do I display all of the items returned from this query in the editor's dropdown?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a setting in the web.config that controls the max number of items that can be returned by a query:

```
<setting name="Query.MaxItems" value="100" />
```

By default, it's set to 100 so I'm not quite sure why your query is only returning 50, perhaps someone else changed the setting?

Also, be wary of a performance hit when returning more than 100 items. Depending on your hardware and overall Sitecore architecture it may not be that noticeable, but just something to be wary of.